# Separating older dogs from puppy when in living room

Tags: dogs, behavior

I have 3 dogs. Two older dogs and one young puppy (1 yr old). Occasional the puppy doesn't hit the "off" switch with wanting to play and you can visible see the other dogs are starting to get annoyed.

As the puppy did not want to stop playing, I deciding to send him in the other area of the house (behind baby gate where he could still see everyone). That area is the "dog" area and has dog beds and toys.  My other 2 dogs laid on the ground in the same room as me.

Is this type of separation bad and will the puppy be resentful or feel "less" than the other dogs? Is there a better way of handling the situation?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is fine though to make it seem like it's not a punishment when you place the puppy in the other area redirect his playfulness to you and give him a nice foraging treat (food stuffed in toys).

It's a nice distraction that benefits both parties.

Answer (score 2):

We only bring our puppy (12 weeks now) into the living area when he (and our other dog) is tired.  Our older dog is usually happily in bed and we supervise the puppy fairly closely to make sure that he stays a close to his blanket as possible (small wandering is ok, but we tempt him back with a toy).

After a little gentle interaction, he'll usually start resting and go to sleep.

Whenever puppy gets too excitable (playing or biting), he goes back into the kitchen to blow off some steam (either plays by himself or with supervision).

Whenever he gets into a nipping mood, he goes into the kitchen by himself or taken to the relief area if he's not been in a while.